# How to handle PreviewKeyDown event in DataGrid when the user has not selected any item. (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I can handle the PreviewKeyDown event when some items of a DataGrid are selected.
But if users don't select any items, the event will not be triggered.
Could I handle the PreviewKeyDown event in this case?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure if that will lead to a something positive. Usually the Control in focus contains the event to which you subscribe, however you have option to make the handler "global" which will be triggered while the window is in focus and then you can loop UI element and find you grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle previewkeydown on the datagrid but something in the datagrid would need to have keyboard focus.

Technically, that can happen without selecting a row.

Even then, you might find a control in the datagrid handles the event.